# Walking into lists of lists?

Tags: recursion, scheme, map-function

I'm wanting to apply `(map fun list)` to a list or the internal lists of a list of lists generically so that the function `(inner-map proc list)` can do the following:

```
plain list(1d):
   (inner-map even? '(1 2 3))
   => (#f #t # f)

list of lists(2d):
   (inner-map even? '((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))
   => ((#f #t #f) (#f #t #f) (#f #t #f))

list of lists of lists (3d):
   (inner-map even? '(((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))
                      ((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))
                      ((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))))
   => (((#f #t #f) (#f #t #f) (#f #t #f)) ((#f #t #f) (#f #t #f) (#f #t #f)) ((#f #t #f) (#f #t #f) (#f #t #f)))
 ad nauseum
```

while not sure on a generic, I can make it work for one dimensionality of a list at a time like so:

```
2d list:
(define (inner-map proc lis)       
  (map (lambda (y)
         (map (lambda (x)
                (proc x))
              y))
       lis))


3d list:
(define (inner-map proc lis)
  (map (lambda (z)
         (map (lambda (y)
                (map (lambda (x)
                       (proc x))
                     y))
              z))
       lis))

And even 4d list structs:
(define (inner-map proc lis)
  (map (lambda (l)
         (map (lambda (k)
                (map (lambda (j)
                       (map (lambda (i)
                              (proc i))
                            j))
                     k))
              l))
       lis))
```

So to make it work generically for lists of any depth you would need to make recursive calls that nest the `(map (lambda (var) ...var))`s deeper until you reach a list of atomics. While this doesn't work this is my stab at the problem:

```
(define (inner-map proc lis)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (cond ((atom? (car lis)) (proc x)))
         (else (inner-map proc x)))
       lis))
```

EDIT: So while I am still learning about higher order functions, would a fold or recursive folds be appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

The only issue with your `inner-map` function is that `(atom? (car lis))` should be `(atom? x)`. There was also close parentheses in the wrong place. Consider:

```
(define (inner-map proc lis)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (cond ((atom? x) (proc x))
               (else (inner-map proc x))))
       lis))
```

Comment: This does not work, Your inner map also is missing a close paren somewhere, it closes if you put it at the end, but I'm not certain if that is where you are wanting to put it at. If I put the close paren at the end so the end looks like `lis)))`, and call `(inner-map even? li)` where  `(define li (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6)), I get "the procedure #[compiled-procedure 64 (map "list #x6f) #xf #x22aced7] has been called with 1 argument; it requires at least 2 arguments.

Comment: sorry never mind, it does work, but only if you add the missing paren so that `(else (inner-map proc x))))`

Answer (score 1):

@dan-d already answered your question with the proper code. I'll add the following analysis.

Your last chunk of code compiles because the variable `lis` is in scope for the lambda, so `(atom? (car lis))` works syntactically, although fails algorithmically. The function `map` operates on every element in the list, which means that the `x` passed to the lambda function is (iteratively) every element of the list. Meanwhile, `(car lis)` grabs the first element of `lis` always, so you only make the choice to recursively call `proc` on `x` based upon the type of the first element rather than the type of the current element.

That was the bug.

The power of lambda in Scheme comes from its ability to capture current state of all variables within its scope. A reference to `lis`, although not passed into your lambda, was grabbed from outside the scope of that lambda and from within the scope of the `inner-map` function.